# Merge rows with identical ID - SWIFT

Tags: swift

I have edited & simplified my question.

This is my current data.

```
struct Account{
        public let accId: String
        public let accName: String
        public let amount: Int
    }
    
let accounts = [
        Account(accId: "A", accName: "Account A", amount: 10),
        Account(accId: "A", accName: "Account A", amount: 4),
        Account(accId: "B", accName: "Account B", amount: 2),
        Account(accId: "C", accName: "Account C", amount: 3)
    ]
```

This is what I want to achieve. I want to merge the rows which have identical accId and sum the amount.

```
let mergedAccounts = [
        Account(accId: "A", accName: "Account A", amount: 14),
        Account(accId: "B", accName: "Account B", amount: 2),
        Account(accId: "C", accName: "Account C", amount: 3)
    ]
```

I tried this, but it will only group them but not merge them.(@BJBeecher)

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: Budget, by: \.accId)
```

And i also tried this, it does merge them but it will output the [accId : amount] only, leaving out the accName.

```
let sumAmountByAccount = selectedBudget.reduce(into: [:]) { (result, offer)  in
    result[offer.accId] = (result[offer.accId] ?? 0 ) + offer.amount}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: selectedBudgetAmount is what type of array? Int or String or anything else?

Comment: This would be so much easier if you used a struct with 4 properties and one array instead of 4 different arrays

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I've implemented your suggestion. Still not sure how to get the sum of amount by account while being able to display all the fields in a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it work. I was able to get the results that I wanted by doing the following:

1. I added standard account details that don't change.

```
let accountDetails = [
    AccDetailsModel(accId: "A", accName: "Account A"),
    AccDetailsModel(accId: "B", accName: "Account B"),
    AccDetailsModel(accId: "C", accName: "Account C")
]
```

2. Summed the total amount by account

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: accounts, by: \.accId)
let sumAmountByAccount = accounts.reduce(into: [:]) { (result, offer)  in
    result[offer.accId] = (result[offer.accId] ?? 0 ) + offer.amount
}
```

3. Then did the following to merge the total with accId & bankName.

```
var mergedResult = [Account]()
var accountName = String()

for (key, value) in sumAmountByAccount {
    for data in accountDetails {
        if data.accId == key {
            accountName = data.accName
        }
    }
    mergedResult.append(Account.init(accId: key, accName: accountName, amount: value))
}
print(mergedResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating the question. The first thing that I would do is abstract your account metadata into a new type and go from there. Here's what I got...

```
// model seperation by composition

struct Account : Hashable {
    let accId: String
    let accName: String
}

struct Order {
    let account : Account
    let amount: Int
}

struct AccountTotal {
    let account : Account
    let totalAmount: Int
}

// how to group and get totals

let seq = [Order]()

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: seq, by: \.account)

let accountTotals = dict.map { (account, orders) -> AccountTotal in
    // reduce orders to get total
    let totalAmount = orders.reduce(0) { total, order in total + order.amount }
    // return new account total
    return .init(account: account, totalAmount: totalAmount)
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I have tried doing so with success, but I still could not get the sum of amount by accountId while being able to display all the fields in a new table. How do I access & display the grouped collection in a table?

Comment: You could then reduce the results.. I'll update my answer to give you some more insight.

Comment: This is what I get when I try to map it, "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate". I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Int type of array for selectedBudgetAmount, you can use like this

```
let amount = selectedBudgetAmount.reduce(0, +)
```

or if you string type of array then you can use like this

```
let amount = selectedBudgetAmount.reduce(0, { lastSum, currentData in
    lastSum + (Double(currentData) ?? 0.0) // <- Change Double type to as per your requirement. if needed.
})
```

or if your array is Model type then you can use like this

```
// Your Data Model
struct DataModel {
    var type: String
    var amount: Double
}
```

```
let amount = selectedBudgetAmount.reduce(0, { lastSum, currentData in
    lastSum + currentData.amount
})
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear.